# Ramaze Request Parameters in Unicode?

Tags: unicode, request, ramaze

I've got a partial for rendering a form that is throwing an error using unicode; I've narrowed the error down to the line;

```
<input name='q' value='#{request.params['q']}' />
```

If I go to `localhost/thepath?q=中文` it throws

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError at /thepath/
incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
```

But

```
<input name='q' value='中文' />
```

Works fine, and all the unicode strings from values that aren't in the request work fine also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to wash the input with `#force_encoding`, is there a more desirable method?